# How do I open a websocket connection to cloud from location behind corporate proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, websocket

I have a nodejs websocket server running in the cloud to which I can make a secured web socket connection from any location outside of corporate firewall.
 Now, how can I provide proxy information while creating a websocket connection from a resource behind corporate proxy (on-premise)? I am using this nodejs module from https://github.com/websockets/ws.

I get EHOSTUNREACH error when I execute following code. Please note there is no vpn connection between cloud resource and the on premise resource.

```
**var wss = new WebSocket('wss://cloudserver:443', {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    });**
```

With a sample code like below, I am able to make http connection to cloud from a resource behind corporate proxy using proxy information , but can't figure out how to make it work with the web sockets.

```
    **var Http = require('http');

    var req = Http.request({
        host: 'proxy',
        port: 8080,
        method: 'GET',
        path: 'http://cnn.com/' // full URL as path
    }, function (res) {
        res.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log(data.toString());
        });
    });

    req.end()

**
```

I also looked at following http://blog.vanamco.com/proxy-requests-in-node-js/ and it seems to have what I need, but as I am new to nodejs I am somewhat lost here.

Comment: Are you using an actual real URL in place of `'wss://cloudserver:443'` with a real and functioning domain?

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned, I am able to open secured web socket connection to it from my home but not from work. The actual url is of course different.

Answer (score 0):

Well `EHOSTUNREACH` implies that no network route can be found to the IP address that DNS provides for the targeted server.

This can either be a DNS error from the local DNS server (wrong IP address) or a routing error (wrong or missing route to that IP address) or possibly there is purposely no route to the target address (private network or corp network blocking things).

You could check the DNS side of things by seeing if you get the same IP address for that host from both work and home.  A simple `ping hostname` will show you the IP address.  If the target server supports ping requests, it will also tell you if the host is reachable.  You could also examine `tracert hostname` from both home and work and see where things get lost.

Comment: well, the second code segment I shared works well from work, which suggests that as long as I use proxy I am able to connect to any outside resource. It's just that the first code segment should be tweaked to use the proxy information. Ping to any outside urls including the one in question from work doesn't work .

Comment: @user702886 - It sounds like a proxy/firewall from work that is preventing anything but straight HTTP requests.  It's a bit odd because a webSocket connection starts life as a plain HTTP request (with a few headers set) which you would think would get through the corp infrastructure unless they are specifically blocking webSocket requests by looking for those headers and denying them.  One possibility would be to use socket.io which will auto fallback to long HTTP polling if the webSocket connection does not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect to my cloud instance by providing proxy information using websocket-node (https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/)
module as below. The actual url is replaced with 'xxx' for security reasons. Thanks everyone who tried to help.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var client = new WebSocketClient();
var tunnel = require('tunnel');
var net = require('net');

var tunnelingAgent = tunnel.httpsOverHttp({
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  proxy: {
      host: 'xxxxxxxx',
      port: 8080,
  }
});



var requestOptions = {
    agent: tunnelingAgent,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    strictSSL: false,
    requestCert: false,
};

var headers = {

};


client.connect('wss://xxxxxx',null, 'xxxxxx', headers, requestOptions);
```